# How to debug grape api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grape-api

```
module Employee
    class Data < Grape::API
        resource :employee_data do 
            desc "Description of all employees"
            get do 
                EmpDatum.all
            end

            desc "create a new employee"
                params do 
                    requires :name, type: String
                    requires :address, type: String
                    requires :age, type: Integer
                end
                post  do
                    EmpDatum.create!({
               name: params[:name],
               address: params[:address],
               age: params[:age]

                        })
                end
            end
    end
end
```

Get request is working fine. However when sent a POST request,

`curl http://localhost:3000/api/v1/employee_data.json -d "name='jay';address='delhi';age=25"`

```
{"error":"address is missing, age is missing"}%
```

I am unable to put `byebug` in the above post block. I am unable to see the params that are getting passed. What am I missing here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your API implementation. However, you're using cURL incorrectly. Make a call like this:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:3000/api/v1/employee_data.json -d '{"name":"jay","address":"Delhi","age":"25"}'
```

Moreover, I'm not sure what **bybug** is but I've been using **RubyMine** for a while and it's perfect to debug Ruby Grape APIs. If you're not successful using **bybug** you can see what you're receiving in your API method just replacing your method code with this:

```
puts params.inspect
```

For example:

```
module Employee
    class Data < Grape::API
        resource :employee_data do 
            desc "Description of all employees"
            get do 
                EmpDatum.all
            end

            desc "create a new employee"
            params do 
                requires :name, type: String
                requires :address, type: String
                requires :age, type: Integer
            end
            post  do
                puts params.inspect
            end
        end
    end
end
```